# Is it possible to play from Google Play (Music) in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, google

Wouldn't it be nice to be able to access Google Player (former Google Music) directly from Rhythembox?
Nuvola Player is nice but standalone player. Is there a similar Rhythembox plugin or any current ongoing work on such?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a daap plugin for Google Music here that is currently unmaintained: https://github.com/dpogue/gmusic-daap. From the author:

> Unfortunately the DAAP library I started with doesn't support some of the options that iTunes looks for. It works with Rhythmbox and Banshee on Linux, and someone told me that it worked with an Android DAAP client. [[1](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3650327)]

---

Another option: I'm working on an unofficial api for Google (Play) Music, and it currently supports everything needed to build such a plugin. The author of the linked daap plugin is working with me.

It's in Python, and there's a C# port in progress. I may port some features into Java, too.

Here's the link: https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

There is a plugin:

https://github.com/nvbn/rhythmbox-gmusic

It works fine, just you cannot filter by artist but it can see your gmusic playlists