# Is there an Ubuntu app that connects to, plays, and/or manages Google Music?

Tags: software-recommendation, webapps, google

I'm looking for a program that I can use for **Google Music** on my Ubuntu Desktop, that might integrate with Unity, and be controlled by media keys. I'm sure I might be most likely to see a webapp for it soon, but I've been getting frustrated with webapps since I use Chrome (not Chromium).

I found a question/answer similar to this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113732/is-it-possible-to-play-from-google-play-music-in-rhythmbox), but I'm looking for something more out-of-the-box than extending Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Nuvola Player](http://nuvolaplayer.fenryxo.cz/home.html)

It integrates with Unity, you can use media keys, and it currently supports Google Play, Amazon Cloud Player, Deezer, Pandora Radio, and Rdio.

Comment: in what sense is this a player? it is just a simplified webkit browser page with bookmarks directing to streaming sites, which are then accessed as with any browser.

Comment: integration is not present in KDE